# Getting the Final redirected URL from within PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell, google-chrome-extension

I'm finding similar answers, but not exactly what I'm needing.

The backstory: I'm trying to write a powershell script that will scrape the Chrome and Microsoft Edge (chromium-based) extensions directory and output the name, ID, and version into a custom WMI class so that my endpoint management agent can accurately reflect user-installed extensions within the inventory record.

In Chrome, this is reasonably easy even if the manifest.json doesn't include a human-readible "name" property, because you can simply take the ID (which is the top level folder of that extension) and run the following:

```
<#
# Chrome URL's are "https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/" + obj.ID
# Edge URL's are "https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/" + obj.ID
#>

$url = "https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/" + obj.ID
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
try
{
   $data = $wc.downloadstring($url)    
   $titletag = [regex] '(?<=<title>)([\S\s]*?)(?=</title>)' 
   $title = $titletag.Match($data).value.trim()    
   $obj.Name = $title
}
catch{
   $obj.Name = "Unknown - Please search manually"
}
```

While both Edge and Chrome webstores will redirect when you put the above links in a browser address bar (example, ***https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/ipnhpapgpnoadggfoepbedokgppcodkl*** redirects to ***https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/notifier-for-github/ipnhpapgpnoadggfoepbedokgppcodkl***), Google actually makes this easier as they include the extension's title in the  tag on the HTML without the redirect necessary.

So in the above example, running that code against Google's webstore would result in **"Notifier for GitHub - Chrome Web Store"**

Edge, however, does not, and the only thing it returns as the title tag is **"Microsoft Edge Addons"**

I have attempted to try to find the redirected URL with this code:

```
Function Get-RedirectedUrl {
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String]$url
    )

    $request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
    $request.AllowAutoRedirect=$true
    $request.UserAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT; Windows NT 10.0; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/7.0.500.0 Safari/534.6'
    
    try
    {
        $response = $request.GetResponse()
        $response.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri
        $response.Close()
    }
    catch
    {
        "Error: $_"
    }
}

$url = 'https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/gmgoamodcdcjnbaobigkjelfplakmdhh'

Get-RedirectedUrl -URL $url
```

But the only thing that does is spit out the same URL I supplied it, so I'm guessing that the redirection happens within JavaScript somehow, but I have no idea how it's doing that.

If there are better ways to try to scrape the extensions' names (that doesn't rely on the manifest.json, because some of them are like this

"name": "**MSG_name_releasebuild**",

I'm definitely open to that if you have suggestions. Otherwise, the only way I know right off hand is to try to grab the title from the actual HTML that can be downloaded from the webclient.

My only real caveat is that to accomplish what I am needing, I would greatly prefer to stay within the realms of PowerShell if at all possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Extensions/` directory in the user profile doesn't include the unpacked developer-mode extensions and as you discovered there's a problem of extracting the name.

**Solution:**

1. read and parse the `Secure Preferences` or `Preferences` file
2. normal extensions have a human-readable `name` and `version` inside `manifest` property
3. unpacked extensions need reading their manifest.json directly and optionally expanding the message id from extension's `_locales` directory.

```bsh
'Secure Preferences', 'Preferences' |
    %{ gc ($env:LOCALAPPDATA + '/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/' + $_) -raw } |
    ConvertFrom-Json |
    ?{ $_.extensions.settings } |
    %{ $_.extensions.settings.PSObject.Properties } |
    %{
        $info = $_.Value
        $name = $info.manifest.name
        $version = $info.manifest.version
        if (!$name -or !$version) {
            Push-Location $info.path
            $manifest = gc 'manifest.json' -raw | ConvertFrom-Json
            $name = $manifest.name
            $version = $manifest.version
            if ($name -cmatch '^__MSG_(\w+?)__$') {
                $msgId = $Matches[1]
                $msgFile = '_locales/' + $manifest.default_locale + '/messages.json'
                $name = (gc -raw $msgFile | ConvertFrom-Json).$msgId.message
            }
            Pop-Location
        }
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            id=$_.Name;
            name=$name;
            version=$version;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I greatly appreciate your answer, though it is not working for me. I don't know if this is relevant, but we are on a domain and our Chrome and Edge is (sort of) managed via GPO for some settings. When I try to spit out any information using your script, I get nothing. A ver batim copy-paste results in an error on line 9 that it cannot find C:\users\username\manifest.json. I believe this to be because in my particular case Secure Preferences doesn't have anything useful in it that I can see. If you would like me to upload that file or the whole Chrome directory, please let me know. I'm stumped.

Comment: It's not that the Secure Preferences file isn't at the path supplied, it's that the file itself doesn't have the information your script is looking for. If I copy the first 6 lines of your script and add a closing brace and run that, then try to echo out $name or $version, they're both blank. I can echo info out as far as the first two lines, $prefs has `@{super_mac=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}` where the X's are a long 65 digit string. Trying to pull info from $prefs.extensions.settings.PSObject.Properties is the failing point, and everything past that point is null.

Comment: That said, I am going to spin up a VM on a consumer Windows that's not domain joined and see if I get the same results

Comment: Aha! I found the secret. Turns out, the information I was looking for was not under Secure Preferences, but simply Preferences. Changing that one thing from line 1 is giving me exactly what I needed! Thanks a ton, wOxxOm!

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the code to incorporate your findings.