# Scanning for Chrome extenstions, including manually-added extenstions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i would like to know if there's a way to scan for ALL of chrome's extenstions.
This includes extensions that are manually loaded(/added) by a user or a script.
For example, an extension loaded manually from a directory called ../Desktop/extension will appear in the scan.

By definition, all ***downloaded*** chrome extensions are located in: C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions

But there is no default location for ***manually-added*** extenstions.
I confirmed this by creating a manuall extension that does nothing except then popping an alert.
The following shows that there is a custom path for the manually-loaded extension:

[The extension's ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vfatn.png)

[The ID doesn't appear in the default location path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6DqP.png)

[The extension has it's own path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZ6JK.png)

**TLDR;**
Is there a way to get the custom extensions without scanning the entire system?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Yes, use 'Secure Preferences' or 'Preferences' file in the browser profile directory, it's a standard JSON so you can parse it in almost any language, here's an example for PowerShell: [Getting the Final redirected URL from within PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63047299)

Comment: @wOxxOm Found it, Thanks!